# Wordpress AJAX Load More Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I just found this script https://github.com/tokmak/wp-load-more-ajax and I wanted to add it into my template.. All good, I added the script from functions.php into my template functions.php, copied the js file in my template folder and added that line from your_template.php into my template page where my posts are shown, the button appear but it doesnt work..

I have every file loaded, I checked but still it does nothing..

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post-box">      
                <div style="float:left; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-right:20px;"> <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID); } else { echo my_post_thumbnail_html(); } ?> </div>
                <div class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></div>           
                <div class="post-content"> <?php excerpt(10); ?> </div>
                <br clear="all" />      
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
            <a class="load_more" data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('load_posts') ?>" href="javascript:;">Load more</a>         
        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is my code.. I dont know what to do..

Answer (score 0):

You must have a loaded content template.
Once, you create a template and add new page with this template. Your page link example: http://localhost.dev/?page_id=1453
This template containt only post loop. You can develop this template with $_GET params(numberposts, category etc.)

```
function loadMore(e, numberposts) {
    $('.show-more', e).text('Loading...');
    $('<div>').load('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/get_loop_template.php?s=' + numberposts, function(r) {
        $('.list-articles .btn-getmore').remove();
        $('.list-articles').append(r);
    });
}
```

This function get your posts, remove current "getmore-buton" than insert posts and add new "getmore-buton".

Comment: Well.. Thank you for your reponse but.. Im just a designer that started working on his own wordpress template.. and it proved that is harder then he thought.. So.. I did everything that tokmak did there + I added that function of yours and it gave me this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)" What I dont understand is.. I need to create one more template for the posts that are loaded through that button ? Also.. From what I was, the button that I have from tokmak script its trying to call a javascript "href="javascript:;" here Im lost..

Comment: Did you add endwhile after my shared code? If you not, add <?php endwhile; ?> after "<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>". for get-more link you can use same as "<a href="javascript:ladMore(10)">load it</a>"

Comment: Man.. Im more confused now.. The only code that you've shared is the function.. You said something about a template containing post loop but the link you gave me isn't working.. its the link from your local machine :-s.. Anyway.. I learned so many things about wordpress just from failing to get this working :))